# rosmake + make test? Automated testing?

Tags: ros, rostest, unit-testing, gtest

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am wondering how I could automate the build of my unit tests.

Because right now I have to call `make test` in every package.
But I would like to automate this, to build for every package that has a test in it.

Something like a `rosmake` command for testing would be ideal.
Or can I add something to the makefile, so rosmake will also build the test?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64393/rosmake-+-make-test?-automated-testing?/) by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on ROS Answers with karma: 496 on 2013-06-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, I should have searched for rosmake options. ;-)
There is a command `rosmake [PACKAGE] -t` that builds and tests the package.
But it calls `make test` only for the package specified and not for the packages it depends on...

---

Originally posted by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) with karma: 496 on 2013-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I reached the same conclusion: there is, AFAIK, no way of building and running tests for all package dependencies of a given package.
'rosmake -t foo' will only compile and run the tests for package 'foo', but not for its dependencies.

I wrote a small script to do that. This script calls 'make test' in all dependencies of the given package and presents the results in a fancy way.
Available here, hope it helps!
https://sites.google.com/site/rameyarnaud/misc/ros/ros-unit-tests-compilation

---

Originally posted by [anonymous2054](https://answers.ros.org/users/2054/anonymous2054/) with karma: 101 on 2013-10-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2